# File Counter in python or last 5 files

Tags: python, counter

I am trying to get a list of the 5 most recently imported pictures into a folder to feed into a function loading them into a contact sheet.

I have a program bringing in files and it uses a counter to name them 00001, 00002 etc...  I was thinking something like

```
while blah:
N = '0000'x
x = x+1
```

but this breaks down when you get above 10, because now it's 00010.

I feel like I should be able to figure this out, but it's totally escaping me.

on the other hand, if I could just have the program load the X newest files into the function, that would also work great.

Image names are run through this formula.

```
 imgs = [Image.open(fn).resize((photow,photoh)) for fn in fnames]
```

so I think they need to be in the format ('00001.jpg','00002.jpg','00003.jpg'.....)

thanks for  help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> '{:05}'.format(10)
00010
```

As for sorting files based on this numbering:

```
import os

# List all files in current directory
files = os.listdir('.')
recent_images = sorted(files)[-5:]
```

Comment: for the listdir command, is there a way to get only files with a certain extension.  It keeps adding thumbs.db to the file list...

Comment: You could try `files = ifilter(lambda x: x.endswith('.<extension>'), os.listdir('.'))`

Answer (score 1):

> on the other hand, if I could just have the program load the X newest
>   files into the function, that would also work great.

You can use [`os.path.getmtime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime) and `sorted` to get a list of most recently changed file:

```
>>> import os
>>> sorted(filenames, key=lambda x:os.path.getmtime(x), reverse=True)[:5]
```

Related: [How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python)